# How compile/install php-mapscript on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mapserver, ubuntu, php, compile

I need to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 but php5 is not officially supported on Ubuntu 16. I install php5.5 by `ondrej` repo https://askubuntu.com/a/756186/483814
but when I try to install `php5-mapscript` on it i get error :

```
root@ubuntu16:~# apt-get install php5-mapscript
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mapscript is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mapscript' has no installation candidate
```

Therefore i try to compile and install php-mapscript from scratch but i don't find any updated and working manual.

So if somebody done it before or have general knowledge about mapserver compilation or if know how to install it from repositories please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @ThomasG77 i did compile and install php5-mapscript of Mapserver7.0.2 
compiled and got loaded successfully:
[image]

The manual is based on mapserver general compile documentations:
http://www.mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#compiling

Here is the manual I follow to compile [Ubuntu 16.04 /PHP 5.5.38-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1]:

1. installing php5.5:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install php5.5
   ```
2. download and extract mapserver source and change directory:

   ```
   wget http://download.osgeo.org/mapserver/mapserver-7.0.2.tar.gz
   tar xvf mapserver-7.0.2.tar.gz
   cd mapserver-7.0.2/
   ```
3. install cmake

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cmake
   ```
4. make `build` directory and change to it [~/mapserver-7.0.2/build]:

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   ```
5. install compile requirement

   ```
   apt-get install libfreetype6-dev 
   apt-get install php5.5-dev
   apt-get install libproj-dev
   apt-get install libfribidi-dev
   apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev
   apt-get install libcairo-dev
   apt-get install libgdal-dev
   apt-get install libgpg-dev
   ```
6. config , compile and install

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt \
           -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/91:/usr/local:/opt \
           -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON \
           -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
           -DWITH_CURL=ON \
           -DWITH_SOS=ON \
           -DWITH_PHP=ON \
           -DWITH_FCGI=OFF \
           -DWITH_PYTHON=OFF \
           -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=OFF \
           ../ >../configure.out.txt
   make
   make install
   echo extension=php_mapscript.so>/etc/php/5.5/mods-available/mapscript.ini
   phpenmod mapscript
   service apache2 restart
   ```

Answer (score 4):

**First answer**

Don't try to compile Mapscript on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP as long as your PHP version is not 5.x.

It will not work for the simple reason that supported PHP version in Ubuntu 16.04 is 7.0 and infortunately for you PHP 7 and MapScript are incompatible at the moment. You can see the [related opened issue](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/5252) on the official MapServer Github repository.

The best solution IMO is simply to not upgrade: the support for 14.04 end in April 2019 ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases))

**Addition**

You need when you compile to be sure to have PHP headers (the package is usually named `php-dev` or `php5.6-dev`) and to set the cmake option to support PHP like illustrated in the section http://www.mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#compiling

Comment: I know it and don't want to compile it on php 7 I want to compile it based on php5.5.36 from ondrej repository.

Comment: Made addition for some compiling help.

Comment: At first i should solve this problem:
FREETYPE library/component could not be found and is a mandatory dependency

Comment: `apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` Deduced from http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/source/xenial/mapserver

Comment: apt-get install libfreetype6-dev 
apt-get install libproj-dev
apt-get install libfribidi-dev

Comment: what about swig?

Comment: Again, reusing previous link in my comments `apt-get install swig`

Comment: it likes it needs fastcgi?

Comment: DSO Is Not Possible?

Comment: Do not know here. I was but now? See list of options in https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/blob/branch-7-0/CMakeLists.txt to maybe find the wanted option(s). Seems to be WITH_APACHE_MODULE but noted as experimental...

Comment: it's ok i did it and i'm writing manual

Comment: I am wondering when php 7 will be supported by MapServer. Almost everything on the internet has moved to php 7.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the very helpfull answer of MSS and still (rather frustrated...) waiting for proper PHP-Mapscript-Support in PHP7:

Some hints for compiling Mapscript **MapServer version 7.2.0** under **Debian 9.5** with **PHP 5.6**:

**Step 1:**
(Install PHP 5.6 instead of PHP 5.5)
see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378017/install-php5-6-in-debian-9
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367249/apache2-4-php-5-6-and-php7-1-running-at-the-same-time

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
update-alternatives --config php  
(and select the item with PHP 5.6)  
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php5.6
service apache2 restart
```

**Step 2:**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/mapserver/mapserver-7.2.0.tar.gz
tar xvf mapserver-7.2.0.tar.gz
cd mapserver-7.2.0/
```

**Step 5:**

```
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
apt-get install php5.6-dev
apt-get install libproj-dev
apt-get install libfribidi-dev
apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev
apt-get install libcairo-dev
apt-get install libgdal-dev
apt-get install libgpg-error-dev
```

**Step 6:**

```
cmake 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt 
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local:/opt" 
-DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 
-DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON 
-DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON 
-DWITH_CURL=ON 
-DWITH_SOS=ON 
-DWITH_PHP=ON 
-DWITH_FCGI=OFF 
-DWITH_PYTHON=OFF 
-DWITH_SVGCAIRO=OFF .. >../configure.out.txt
```

(all in one line)

```
make
make install
echo extension=php_mapscript.so>/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/mapscript.ini
ln -s /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/mapscript.ini /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/mapscript.ini  
phpenmod mapscript
service apache2 restart
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The current version of PHP-MapScript is not compatible with PHP7. To compile MapServer with PHP7-MapScript replace the code in ~/mapserver/mapscript/php with the code from https://github.com/bjoernboldt/mapscript-php7. Then run cmake with WITH_PHP=1. Sometimes it is nessecary to add the PHP-Path too.

For example:

cd ~/mapserver

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -D WITH_PHP=1 -D PHP_INCLUDES=/usr/include/php/20151012 ..

make

make install