# How to compile/install php-mapscript with PHP7

Tags: mapserver, php, compile, debian

So, [this PR](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/pull/5687) opens up mapscript support for PHP7. Since there is no ducomentation I gave it a try based on [How compile/install php-mapscript on Ubuntu 16.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217947/how-compile-install-php-mapscript-on-ubuntu-16-04) (although I'm doing it in Debian 9 if that's important).

Here's what I did:

```
apt-get install apache2
#install PHP (PHP7.0 at the time of writing)
apt-get install php
#PR is on the master branch
wget https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
#install cmake
apt-get install cmake
#make build directory and change to it [~/mapserver-7.0.2/build]:
mkdir build
cd build
#install compile requirement
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev 
apt-get install php7.0-dev
apt-get install libproj-dev
apt-get install libfribidi-dev
apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev
apt-get install libcairo-dev
apt-get install libgdal-dev
apt-get install libgpg-error-dev
#config 
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local:/opt" -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON -DWITH_CURL=ON -DWITH_SOS=ON -DWITH_PHP=ON -DWITH_FCGI=OFF -DWITH_PYTHON=OFF -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=OFF .. >../configure.out.txt
#compile
make

#install
make install

#enable mapscript and restart
echo extension=php_mapscript.so>/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mapscript.ini
?
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/mapscript.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/mapscript.ini
?
phpenmod mapscript
service apache2 restart
```

`make` looks fine to me:

```
make
...
[ 98%] Building C object mapscript/php/CMakeFiles/php_mapscript.dir/php_mapscript_util.c.o
[ 99%] Building C object mapscript/php/CMakeFiles/php_mapscript.dir/php_mapscript.c.o
[100%] Building C object mapscript/php/CMakeFiles/php_mapscript.dir/mapscript_i.c.o
/home/deb9/ms72/mapserver/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c: In function ‘mapObj_getMetaData’:
/home/deb9/ms72/mapserver/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c:288:10: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   return(msLookupHashTable(&(self->web.metadata), name));
         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/deb9/ms72/mapserver/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c: In function ‘layerObj_getMetaData’:
/home/deb9/ms72/mapserver/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c:798:10: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   return(msLookupHashTable(&(self->metadata), name));
         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[100%] Linking C shared module php_mapscript.so
[100%] Built target php_mapscript
```

`make install` looks pretty promising, too:

```
make install
...
[ 77%] Built target shptreevis
[ 78%] Built target msencrypt
[ 79%] Built target sortshp
[ 81%] Built target tile4ms
[100%] Built target php_mapscript
Install the project...
...
-- Installing: /opt/share/mapserver/cmake/mapserver-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: /opt/share/mapserver/cmake/mapserverTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /opt/share/mapserver/cmake/mapserverTargets-noconfig.cmake
>>>END
```

As you can see althought it says it builds `php_mapscript` it is not installing it at the end. Thus, `/usr/lib/php/20151012` does not contain `php_mapscript.so`:

```
build         fileinfo.so  opcache.so   shmop.so      sysvshm.so    xmlwriter.so
calendar.so  ftp.so      pdo.so       simplexml.so  tokenizer.so  xsl.so
ctype.so     gettext.so   phar.so      sockets.so    wddx.so
dom.so         iconv.so      posix.so     sysvmsg.so    xmlreader.so
exif.so      json.so      readline.so  sysvsem.so    xml.so
```

`phpinfo()` obvioulsy does not list MapScript as a module. So this somehow did not work.

So, to cross-check this, I tried the same (well, almost obviously) with PHP5.6:

```
apt-get install apache2

apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
update-alternatives --config php
(and select the item with PHP 5.6)  
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php5.6
service apache2 restart

wget http://download.osgeo.org/mapserver/mapserver-7.2.0.tar.gz
tar xvf mapserver-7.2.0.tar.gz
cd mapserver-7.2.0/

wget https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/archive/branch-7-2.zip
unzip branch-7-2.zip
cd mapserver-branch-7-2
mkdir build
cd build

apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
apt-get install php5.6-dev
apt-get install libproj-dev
apt-get install libfribidi-dev
apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev
apt-get install libcairo-dev
apt-get install libgdal-dev
apt-get install libgpg-error-dev
apt-get install cmake

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local:/opt" -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON -DWITH_CURL=ON -DWITH_SOS=ON -DWITH_PHP=ON -DWITH_FCGI=OFF -DWITH_PYTHON=OFF -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=OFF .. >../configure.out.txt
make
make install
echo extension=php_mapscript.so>/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/mapscript.ini
ln -s /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/mapscript.ini /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/mapscript.ini  
phpenmod mapscript
service apache2 restart
```

`make` looks just like the PHP7 try to me:

```
make
...
[ 98%] Building C object mapscript/php/CMakeFiles/php_mapscript.dir/php_mapscript_util.c.o
[ 99%] Building C object mapscript/php/CMakeFiles/php_mapscript.dir/php_mapscript.c.o
[100%] Building C object mapscript/php/CMakeFiles/php_mapscript.dir/mapscript_i.c.o
/home/deb9/Downloads/mapserver-branch-7-2/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c: In function ‘mapObj_getMetaData’:
/home/deb9/Downloads/mapserver-branch-7-2/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c:288:10: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   return(msLookupHashTable(&(self->web.metadata), name));
         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/deb9/Downloads/mapserver-branch-7-2/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c: In function ‘layerObj_getMetaData’:
/home/deb9/Downloads/mapserver-branch-7-2/mapscript/php/mapscript_i.c:798:10: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   return(msLookupHashTable(&(self->metadata), name));
         ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[100%] Linking C shared module php_mapscript.so
[100%] Built target php_mapscript
```

`make install` is similar but installs `php_mapscript` as well:

```
make install:
...
[ 77%] Built target shptreevis
[ 78%] Built target msencrypt
[ 79%] Built target sortshp
[ 81%] Built target tile4ms
[100%] Built target php_mapscript
Install the project...
...
-- Installing: /opt/share/mapserver/cmake/mapserver-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: /opt/share/mapserver/cmake/mapserverTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /opt/share/mapserver/cmake/mapserverTargets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mapscript.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mapscript.so" to "/opt/lib"
>>>END
```

`/usr/lib/php/20131226` now contains `php_mapscript.so`:

```
build         ftp.so     pdo.so           shmop.so    tokenizer.so
calendar.so  gettext.so  phar.so       sockets.so
ctype.so     iconv.so     php_mapscript.so  sysvmsg.so
exif.so      json.so     posix.so       sysvsem.so
fileinfo.so  opcache.so  readline.so       sysvshm.so
```

`phpinfo()` lists MapScript as a module, just like in @MSS's post/screnshot in [How compile/install php-mapscript on Ubuntu 16.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217947/how-compile-install-php-mapscript-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Any hints or ideas to get mapscript to work with PHP7? Is there some flaw in my workflow?

Comment: Just tested this further and @Björn's Fork (https://github.com/bjoernboldt/mapserver) worked like a charme using the same workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install command is commented out in mapserver/master:

https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/blob/master/mapscript/php/CMakeLists.txt#L46

```
install(TARGETS php_mapscript DESTINATION ${PHP_EXTENSION_DIR})
```

The [bjoernboldt branch](https://github.com/bjoernboldt/mapserver/blob/fd3cbf6cb23c7a558893e7e11cde419049ea4fdf/mapscript/php/CMakeLists.txt#L39) has this included. I'm not sure if this is due to issues with different destination directories for different PHP versions, or an oversight.

Could you try uncommenting and rebuilding?

Comment: I tried this and I think it was what made mapscript available. Is this an error which should be reported?